# Why cannot pickle 'QListWidgetItem' object?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I am writing an application, I want to save widget values (ideally, I would find some function that does it all, but apparently there are none), I am writing a crutch to save values, but at the moment of saving the QListWidget elements, an error pops up:

```
cannot pickle 'QListWidgetItem' object


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)

    def _get_saving_types(self) -> list:
        return [
            (QLineEdit, ["setText", "text"]),
            (QCheckBox, ["setChecked", "isChecked"]),
            (QListWidget, ["addItems"]),
        ]
    def loadState(self):
        settings = QSettings('gui.ini', QSettings.Format.IniFormat)
        for type, method in self._get_saving_types():
            for widget in self.findChildren(type):
                if settings.value(widget.objectName()) is not None:
                    methodcaller(method[0], settings.value(widget.objectName()))(widget)
        pass
    
    def saveState(self):
        settings = QSettings('gui.ini', QSettings.Format.IniFormat)
        for type, method in self._get_saving_types():
            for widget in self.findChildren(type):
                if isinstance(widget, QListWidget):
                    items = []
                    for index in range(widget.count()):
                        items.append(widget.item(index))
                    settings.setValue(widget.objectName(), items) # an error occurs here
                    pass
                else:
                    settings.setValue(widget.objectName(), methodcaller(method[1])(widget))
```

Please help me.

Comment: You cannot pickle anything, you can only do that with basic python types, and QListWidgetItem certainly isn't. Use the [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidgetitem.html#text) function of QListWidgetItem.

Comment: As well as the basic python types, PyQt6 [supports pickling of a few Qt classes](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pickle.html). Broadly speaking, this includes anything that can be stuffed into a QVariant (which obviously does not apply to QListWidgetItem). But in any case, since [QListWidget.addItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#addItems) takes *a list of strings*, the point is moot. Your code example can be fixed by simply doing this: `items.append(widget.item(index).text())`.

Comment: I also need to save the flags of each QListWidgetItem